# HTML / CSS - (Float: left) does not work

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

*in application.scss*

```
.message-sent {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  border-color: #BCE8F1;
  margin: 5px 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
}


.message-received {
  background-color: #F1F0F0;
  border-color: #EEEEEE;
  margin: 5px 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

*in view/messages/_message.html.erb*

```
<li>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="<%= user.id == message.user_id ? 'message-sent' : 'message-received' %>">
      <%= message.body %>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

*in view/conversations/_conversation.html.erb*

```
<li>
  <div class="panel panel-default" data-conversation-id="<%= conversation.id %>">
    <div style="font-size: 15px; height: 30%;" class="badge badge-pill badge-success">
      <%= link_to conversation.opposed_user(user).nickname, '', class: 'toggle-window' %></div>
      <%= link_to "x", close_conversation_path(conversation), class: "btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right", remote: true, method: :post %>
      <div class="panel-body" style="display: none;">
        <div class="messages-list">
          <ul>
            <%= render 'conversations/conversation_content', messages: conversation.messages, user: user %>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <form class="new_message">
          <input name="conversation_id" type="hidden" value="<%= conversation.id %>">
          <input name="user_id" type="hidden" value="<%= user.id %>">
          <textarea name="body" class="form-control"></textarea>
          <input style="font-size: 13px; height: 30%;" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="전송">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

*
I made real-time chat from rails to actioncable.
I send-message on the right side of the chat window.
I want the receive-message to appear on the left.
In the tutorial it was possible.
But it will not be in my project
All chats appear on the left.
It does not seem to be a problem with scss.
It is correct if you modify the color in scss
If you want additional code, please let me know by comment.*

chrome browser(F12) in the error page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Univ. Community Prototype</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="UNQR3pfc6IF9oi+Wp3fgdvvJSJNQ1AXgrX6R1uroKEtyVyJqyOLxCQ+WEp9wPfca0xfz9DDsOIO9rOMAQ0kfTw==" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-607424cb77179d6e129430471baf980e5ad301867ac29c26b26d7212ad5f08ff.css?body=1" />
    <script src="/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap.self-9acfc28c4d35348d353eb47afc72c287bc271ea4f7e8c9b05f2f9554ddc3f202.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap/util.self-5ae5b599fc2afe0f317696c5dfc0b51d6ce2ecb47d0341d1555b2fe971ada496.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap/alert.self-5a586b490b4c9332249b231956b361b852b128a0d82f7f08549f205bba1bfeb0.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap/button.self-30412f39aaa761313878531076ce8187fe6c017e42111bf2c283fce4a7c850f8.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap/carousel.self-f18afa468f85125228747ec83e00e56a26bbc71295e90a3848af25b258445615.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap/collapse.self-94c7455a70c5bb5ad5b3eae0c70388160c238afdea0b48d5345587fd176fb52d.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap/dropdown.self-954f8384ac380992dd91b2b176b570b0792365a334efb758774c718d9628a329.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap/modal.self-a406636221efb5add01fbaa60c24ac0ae6bc0c57008d8e2503d68f49fbe75ad0.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy.self-66781adda319363e67c65edfc73459411bd3948c0f32efddbc9928b810d5abf4.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap/tab.self-e3abc2817f699a2be95f78a4aff190ef7669d5590adbacd0c08867eb34ed16c6.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap/tooltip.self-dd8a9f3fa1f9fc58df30c7ed9a17dfc7303b812d72640899beee03609124b426.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap/popover.self-7d459fac34d4d96fd9d6da8efcd40dee55b66579a24ddcebf0a355c82dcad7e0.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-sprockets.self-636159b35205da4142a43bc02d2849d77d3ac07a0946211585cde15a9c6ff21f.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-784a997f6726036b1993eb2217c9cb558e1cbb801c6da88105588c56f13b466a.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/tinymce/preinit.self-78bfc36da60c92b71799c55e0d8c68780f19caf3cf4e4e0e3bca8c9014a0d83d.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/tinymce/tinymce.self-b5596bc02a735dc0e7ad551e4a88ecf812f3ab6a8f4355441b3481d869393199.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/tinymce.self-75a11da44c802486bc6f65640aa48a730f0f684c5c07a42ba3cd1735eb3fb070.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.self-c4e34b289f498e7a8e4ff16c48b895310113eae7c296ac5f17680704bc3a0032.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/tinymce-jquery.self-6a3cf5192354f71615ac51034b3e97c20eda99643fcaf5bbe6d41ad59bd12167.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bulletins.self-2abc19c26ebbf605174fbef79b9fbc2861869c60e15935e80dffcad48cabad9f.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/action_cable.self-be3674a79bb9d13d41d259b2c17fad23aef20946dab3603b9d02374ea795005f.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/cable.self-8484513823f404ed0c0f039f75243bfdede7af7919dda65f2e66391252443ce9.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/channels/conversation.self-cff6155dee216e5740d8b35a8bf334e29e4397a573cf1c5e28f292e5c0f95032.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/comments.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/home.self-19a187bec6cdb96d6de80a61c16c857c613536adf9138476bd367db38d282635.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/knu.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/likes.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/members.self-19a187bec6cdb96d6de80a61c16c857c613536adf9138476bd367db38d282635.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/messages.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/posts.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/reports.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/talks.self-19a187bec6cdb96d6de80a61c16c857c613536adf9138476bd367db38d282635.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/application.self-1915efa258d754c8135929322b965317324ccca7ec8d68cc7c42e5f9019e998a.js?body=1"></script>
    
    <!-- jquery, 드랍박스 활성화 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/drop-down.js"></script>
    
    <!-- 카카오톡 썸네일 -->
    <meta property="og:image" content="/img/op_thum.png">
    
    <!-- 개인 CSS / JS -->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/image-box.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/customize.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/count_down.js"></script>
    
    <!-- 부트스트랩 CDN, AWESOME 폰트 CDN -->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/assets/css/docs.min.css">
    
    <!-- 상단 메뉴 관련 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/header_menu.css">
    <script src="/js/highlight.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/theme.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px">
    <div class="header">
  
    <!-- Navigation 상단 메뉴 -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-transparent navbar-toggleable-md fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container no-override">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img style="width: 150px;" src="/img/logo.png" alt="Logo" /></a>
  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/bulletins">카테고리 설정</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">게시판 <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 15px;"></i></a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/bulletins/1/posts">자유게시판</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/bulletins/2/posts">피드백 게시판</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/home/update">Admin</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/home/git"><i class="fa fa-github-alt" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 15px;"></i> Git!</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">장식메뉴2</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/talks/index">쪽지함가기</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/users/edit" class="nav-link board_nickname_etc"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 15px;"></i> 나야나</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link nav-link--rounded" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out">로그아웃</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
 <!-- Navigation 상단메뉴 종료 -->
 
    <div class="board" style="background: url('/img/title_img_1.png') no-repeat center center/cover scroll;"><span style="color: white; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); padding: 10px; border-radius: 10px;"></span></div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <ul id="conversations-list">
        <span style="height: 40%;" class="badge badge-pill badge-info">&nbsp;</span> : 아이디를 누르면 채팅창이 열립니다.
<li>
  <div class="panel panel-default" data-conversation-id="2">
    <div style="font-size: 15px; height: 30%;" class="badge badge-pill badge-success">
      <a class="toggle-window" href="">선풍기</a></div>
      <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/conversations/2/close">x</a>

    <div class="panel-body" style="display: none;">
      <div class="messages-list">
        <ul>
            <li>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="message-sent">
      sadsd
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

        </ul>
      </div>
      <form class="new_message">
        <input name="conversation_id" type="hidden" value="2">
        <input name="user_id" type="hidden" value="3">
        <textarea name="body" class="form-control"></textarea>
        <input style="font-size: 13px; height: 30%;" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="전송">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
        <span style="height: 40%;" class="badge badge-pill badge-info">&nbsp;</span> : 아이디를 누르면 채팅창이 열립니다.
<li>
  <div class="panel panel-default" data-conversation-id="3">
    <div style="font-size: 15px; height: 30%;" class="badge badge-pill badge-success">
      <a class="toggle-window" href="">냉장고</a></div>
      <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/conversations/3/close">x</a>

    <div class="panel-body" style="display: none;">
      <div class="messages-list">
        <ul>
            <li>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="message-sent">
      asdsad
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
  <li>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="message-sent">
      하하하
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

        </ul>
      </div>
      <form class="new_message">
        <input name="conversation_id" type="hidden" value="3">
        <input name="user_id" type="hidden" value="3">
        <textarea name="body" class="form-control"></textarea>
        <input style="font-size: 13px; height: 30%;" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="전송">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
    </ul>
  </div>


<div class="col-md-3">
  <h3 class="alert alert-success" role="alert">쪽지 보내기</h3>
    <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
      <ul>
          <div><li><span style="font-size: 13px;" class="badge badge-pill badge-success"><a data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/conversations?user_id=1">선풍기</a></span></li></div>
          <div><li><span style="font-size: 13px;" class="badge badge-pill badge-success"><a data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/conversations?user_id=2">냉장고</a></span></li></div>
          <div><li><span style="font-size: 13px;" class="badge badge-pill badge-success"><a data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/conversations?user_id=4">Sjeisjd</a></span></li></div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-info">&nbsp;</span> : 닉네임을 누르면 메세지를 전송할 수 있습니다.
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know anything about ruby on rails, but `align` is not a valid CSS property, so I am assuming that is your problem. If you want to float something left or right, use `float: left` or `float: right` as you have in your question title.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I have just modified the code I am trying to test.

Comment: Ah. Well now we have a different problem. `float: center` also isn't valid. It's either left or right. If you want to align something in the middle of the container, you'll have to do something else. For example, `float: left` with a left margin to push the box into the center of the screen. If you could post some example *rendered* html, I could show you some possibilities.

Comment: Oh ... the center was also part of my test. Thank you for your search.
I do not know what html rendering you want.
Do you want my code? Or do you want my site's url?
Of course I will go!

Comment: I mean, can you show some HTML that rails is actually outputting rather than your original html.erb source? Show some pure HTML of what a few messages back and forth looks like. With your recent edits, it's hard to say what the issue would be; everything seems fine on the surface. It could also be that it is some other part of your SCSS that is the problem.

Comment: Ah! Do you want to see the source view page through F12 of my web page?

Comment: That would work. Ideally you'd edit that into the question as code rather than as an image.

Comment: Yes I have attached the source of the problematic page. Through my chrome F12

Comment: In the code you just dropped in, it appears none of the messages show up because their parents are all set to `display: none`. Please edit the snippet again. The snippet doesn't have to look exactly like it does on your production site, but it needs to actually show the problem. All the resources you have in the `<head>` of your document don't work in the snippet because they're all relative paths. You can add just the resources necessary to reproduce the problem to the snippet by clicking the "add an external library" button on the left side of the snippet editor.

Comment: Oh, also I noticed that you have a problem at the end of your header. The closing tags for `div.header` and `nav` need to be switched.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be fixed with some HTML. Just put this below both floats like so:

```
<your right float div>
<your left float div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It has helped a lot.
I have solved your answer by applying it.
An additional question is "clear: both;" Can you tell me exactly what it means?

Comment: @김상열 if two elements are floated and both are narrow enough to fit in their container, they'll show up next to each other. Clearing an element makes sure it doesn't show up next to another one that's floated. [Read more here](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/). You could potentially just add `clear: both` to the floated elements themselves, without adding a new element.

Comment: I prefer to use `clear: both` inside a `div` because there may be certain floats you don't want to clear.